# Фразеологизм «проходит красной нитью» и слово «через»

Tags: грамматика, фразеология

Я заметил, что во всех случаях употребления устойчивого сочетания «проходить красной нитью» вместе с фразеологизмом используется слово «через». Вопрос: если я не буду использовать в этой связке слово «через», это будет ошибкой? Ведь сам же по себе фразеологизм не включает в себя это слово ([https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/проходить_красной_нитью](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E))

Например, предложение «у нас с психологом на всех сеансах красной нитью проходит вопрос» будет ошибочным? И как тогда лучше написать: «у нас с психологом через все сеансы красной нитью проходит вопрос»?

Answer (score 1):

Далеко не всегда с этим фразеологизмом используется слово "через". Среди других предлогов чаще всего встречаются **по, в/во, сквозь**. Любой из этих предлогов может быть уместен в Вашем предложении (в отличие от выбранного Вами предлога "на", я думаю).

Для справки: для поиска в гугле этого фразеологизма без предлога "через" можно задать такой запрос: *красной нитью проходит -через*.

Answer (score 0):

Почему используется предлог «через», может быть понятно из этимологии фразеологизма:

> Из романа «Избирательное сродство душ» (ч. 2, гл. 2; 1809) Иоганна
> Вольфганга Гете (1749—1832): *«Все снасти королевского флота, от самого
> толстого каната до тончайшей веревки, сучатся так, чтобы **через них во
> всю длину проходила красная нить**, которую нельзя выдернуть иначе, как
> распустив все остальное; так что даже по самому маленькому обрывку
> веревки можно узнать, что она принадлежит английской короне;* точно так
> же через весь дневник Оттилии тянется красная нить симпатии и
> привязанности, все сочетающая воедино и знаменательная для целого». До
> 1776 г. в разных подразделениях английского флота эта нить была разных
> цветов, позже ввели единообразный красный цвет — по цвету английского
> военного мундира.
>
> *[[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E)]*

---

Приставка про- в «проходить» в данном случае значит:

> в безударной позиции при добавлении к глаголам образует глаголы **со
> значением направления сквозь, через что-то**
> ◆ буравить → пробуравить ◆
> рвать → прорвать ◆ пилить → пропилить
>
> *[[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-)]*

---

Поэтому красная нить **про**ходит **сквозь/через** канат, верёвку во всю длину.

И в переносном смысле, что-то проходит «через». Как в тексте из [[Викисловаря](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E)]:
«…через дневник…» – принизывает его содержимое от начала до конца.

---

Однако, намой взгляд

*«У нас с психологом через все сеансы красной нитью проходит вопрос…»*

звучит не очень хорошо. Потому что воспринимается как описание самого процесса сеанса, а не содержимого беседы.

> **сеа́нс**, -а, м. 1. Исполнение чего-н. в определённый промежуток времени без перерыва. С. одновременной игры в шахматы. *Портрет
> написан в пять сеансов (за пять сеансов). **С. гипноза.** С. связи (по
> радио, телевидению).*
>
> *[Толковый словарь Ожегова C. И.]*

Таким образом, «сеанс» — это время непрерывной работы психолога с вами. И «через все сеансы», — на мой взгляд, больше характеризует работу психолога, чем содержимое ваших бесед.

---

Предлог «на» в «на всех сеансах», означает не то, через что красная нить проходит, а место действия. Как «на уроке» или «на работе».

> на1, предлог. I. с вин. и предл. п.
> … 
> 2. (на) что и (на) чём. Употр. при обозначении места, области или времени деятельности.
>
> ```
> Орудие на позиции. Выйти на позицию. Быть на работе. Идти на работу. Быть на собрании. Вынести вопрос на собрание. Решить на пленуме. Вынести вопрос на пленум. Встреча на будущей неделе. Отложить на будущую неделю. Быть на выставке. Идти на выставку.
> ```
>
> *[Толковый словарь Ожегова C. И.]*

Поэтому я думаю, что смысл тут такой:

*«У нас с психологом на всех сеансах [место действия] красной нитью проходит [через все наше общение] вопрос»*

Как бы опущено, через что именно проходит, но подразумевается *через общение*.